# Update element in Array of Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update one element of `snippets` in my mongoose schema.

My Mongoose schema.

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
  createdAt: Date,
  snippets: {} // here I push ['string..', ['array of strings..']]
})
```

Here's a view of `snippets` in Compass.

[image]

Problem with the code below is that it completely erases other elements stored, other than that it works. Unable to specify that I want to update snippets[0], not entire thing..?

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.session.user.username },
  { $set: { snippets: [snippet] } }, callback)
```

Tried using `findOne` and`save` but it wouldn't update the db.

```
const snippet = [req.body.code, [req.body.tags]]
User.findOne({ username: req.session.user.username }, function (err, fetchedUser) {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  fetchedUser.snippets[req.params.id] = snippet // should be set to new snippet?
  fetchedUser.save(function (err, updatedUser) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    console.log('edited')
    // ...
  })
})
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I tried this earlier, but apparantly not.

Using `fetchedUser.markModified('snippets')` solved my issue with `findOne`/`save` not actually saving to DB.